# Is it safe to delete IntelliJ's system directory?

Tags: java, caching, ide, intellij-idea, temporary-files

IntelliJ keeps a bunch of cache files in its ["system" directory](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) (settings and downloaded plugins are written to a separate config directory).

Is it safe to delete this directory (not while IntelliJ is running), without losing settings? The reason is that I might put it on a tmpfs, which gets cleared on shutdown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's perfectly safe though there are some quite useful caches there which will be lost. For example, you'll face long project reindexing, rebuild, Maven may decide to re-download the Internet, your VCS repository commits will be re-queried, the statistics used in code completion will be re-queried.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is safe. Alternatively, you can [invalidate caches](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/cleaning-system-cache.html) from inside IntelliJ by choosing the *File* -> *Invalidate Caches...* menu option.